# Should I spread lime in my crawlspace before laying moisture barrier?

Tags: moisture, vapor-barrier, crawlspace

The crawlspace is currently just earth. I'm going to be raking it, laying moisture barrier and then taping to seal.

Should I spread lime onto the earth before laying the barrier?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by spreading lime?

Comment: Lime cam be pretty caustic. If you do, you should use skin and eye protection.

Comment: @bcworkz I want to assist in decomposing any organic matter under the house